# NSDateFormatter Issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

Hi I have a question regarding NSDateFormatter.
Maybe Im missing something but my NSDateFormatter is not adjusting the date correctly only the time:

```
// NSDateFormatter (self.df) initialized in another method.
[self.df setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, YYYY hh:mm a"];
NSString *dpDate = [(UITextField*)[dateCell viewWithTag:101] text];
NSLog(@"tf date: %@",dpDate);
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];
date = [self.df dateFromString:dpDate];
NSLog(@"Date: %@",[self.df stringFromDate:date]);
```

However after printing it seems the date doesn't format correctly Below are a few outputs:

Consult Output 1:

```
xxx[5262:60b] tf date: Dec 05, 2013 09:35 AM

2013-12-05 09:35:17.718 xxx[5262:60b] Date: Dec 23, 2012 09:35 AM
```

Consult Output 2:

```
xxx[5262:60b] tf date: Jan 16, 2014 09:45 AM

2013-12-05 09:36:21.151 xxx[5262:60b] Date: Dec 22, 2013 09:45 AM
```

In addition, I am only setting the dateFormat once.

Comment: The line `NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];` is completely unnecessary.  The date reference immediately overwritten by the next line.

Comment: Well, not completely unnecessary, the declaration is still needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `yyyy`, not `YYYY`. The first is the regular year number (with respect to the configured calendar) and the second is for *week-based* calendar year.

See this [detailed article](http://realmacsoftware.com/blog/working-with-date-and-time) on how to use NSDateFormatter, and the distinction between the two.

Comment: Thank you for this.. and the link to the article.